# Empty GET to AltoRouter

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, altorouter

I'm trying to use [AltoRouter](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter), but I'm trying to follow its documentation and my problem is that `$_GET` always to be empty.

I'm using Apache, and my .htaccess is like the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And now this is my file to take the `$_GET` and make the router:

```
$router->map('GET', '/', 'PageController@getShowHomePage', 'home');
$match = $router->match();

list($controller, $method) = explode("@", $match['target']);

if(is_callable(array($controller, $method))) {
  $object = new $controller();
  call_user_func_array(array($object, $method), array($match['params']));
} else {
  echo "Cannot find $controller -> $method";
  exit();
}
```

But I see that it ins't work, because when I'm receiving the $_GET, it's always empty, I used a `print_r($_GET)` to see within to `$_GET`, but was returned to me a array empty.

I tried with the followings URL's, but the result was the same:

```
http://localhost/mvc/
http://localhost/mvc/page
http://localhost/mvc/controller
http://localhost/mvc/produto/cadastrar
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have no query (GET) params in those urls.
get param would be if you used say:
`http://localhost/mvc?param=1`

you can get more info from `$_SERVER`

if you need help debugging try a tool like [kint](https://raveren.github.io/kint/)